# Pull a web repository into local using Mercurial command

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to pull a Mercurial web repository into my local filesystem to work.  I used the following command but I get the error: `Merucrial Repository (.hg directory not found)`.  But my boss said Mercurial is installed in the machine.

```
    hg pull https://username@web_repository_name
```

What is the proper way to get a working copy of a Mercurial repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start by executing a clone of the repository, after which you can use pull to incrementally add new changes.

These are really the basics of Mercurial, so I would propose you read [this tutorial](http://hginit.com/), followed by [this Mercurial guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/).

Comment: Fantastic. I just need a small clarification. How can i distinguish between the working directory and mercurial repository. I have pulled it to the folder /home/vinod... in this is this the working directory??

Comment: If you are in /home/vinod and do 'hg clone .../somereponame', your repository will be at /home/vinod/somereponame.
Your working directory is also at /home/vinod/somereponame, but the history of the repository will be located in /home/vinod/somereponame/.hg (a directory you shouldn't have to touch, usually).

Comment: When i did a branch, it says the working directory has been marked as a branch... So, how can i go and access that

Comment: I propose you read the tutorial and the Mercurial book, because you are asking additional basic questions that can be answered by reading those.

Comment: Ya i got it.. Thank u very much for the information.